# Can we have a "specific to one company" close reason?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

A lot of questions ask something that could be answered (sometimes very easily) by looking at an employer's policies/rules, or by asking your boss, but can't be answered by our community ([example](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/23189/869)).

The closest close reasons we have to this is "primarily opinion-based":

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

While answers can be based on facts, references, or specific expertise, those facts/expertise are *not relevant* to the particular situation, since policy varies by company (and industry, and locale).

In these situations, the best we can say is "ask your boss" or "check your company policy", which isn't an answer to the question (more of a link-only "the answer is over here" question without an actual link). It would be helpful if we could close these questions as "too localized" or similar.

Comment: I'm down with any close reason that is shorthand for "This question is best answered by reviewing your organization's policies and procedures, and/or talking directly with your manager or HR."

Comment: for the reference, we have one free slot in site-specific off-topic reasons - I just checked that

Comment: I was on vacation and apparently missed this entirely. Following [my recent post requesting another reason to be added](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/) we'd have one too many, so I will make a thread devoted to which reasons we want soon™

Answer (score 7):

I usually use

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations or agreements that are company-specific and don't have universally applicable answers.

As a custom close reason for this type of question. It may need some refinement and I'm open to suggestions. If you like it the way it is, feel free to pick it up!

Comment: I like this.  So long as we have a slot available anyway, I'd like to add it.  (We can have up to three custom off-topic reasons.)